# How could I create a column with matchin values from different datasets with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset, matching

I want to create a new column in the dataset in which a ZipCode is assigned to a specific Region.

There are in total 5 Regions. Every Region consists of an `x` amount of ZipCodes. I would like to use the two different datasets to create a new column.

I tried some codes already, however, I failed because the series are not identically labeled. How should I tackle this problem?

I have two datasets, one of them has **1518 rows** x **3 columns** and the other one has
**46603 rows** x **3 columns**.

[image]

As you can see in the picture:

- `df1` is the first dataset with the `Postcode` and `Regio` columns, which are the ZipCodes assigned to the corresponding `Regio`.
- `df2` is the second dataset where the `Regio` column is missing as you can see. I would like to add a new column into the df2 dataset which contains the corresponding `Regio`.

I hope someone could help me out.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to map the zipcode from dataframe 2 to the region column from the first dataframe. Assuming Postcode and ZipCode are same.

First create a dictionary from df1 and then replace the zipcode values based on the dictionary values

```
zip_dict = dict(zip(df1.Postcode, df1.Regio))
df2.ZipCode.replace(zip_dict)
```

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. I’m going to try your suggestion, hope it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately , this code didn't work for the problem I'm facing. Anyone else with suggestions?

Comment: can you share screenshot of the error

Comment: Actually I didn't get an error. I only created a dictionary, however, I do not know what the following step should be. I would like to create a new column in df2 with the corresponding Regio like df1.

df1 is actually the dataset which is only provided to link the Zip with the corresponding Regio.